# type 'UIViewController' has no member updateTimer

Tags: swift

I'm trying to access the timer property in
the `UIViewController`

For most recent version of swift `UIViewController` doesn't seem to have the member "updateTimer"

```
class InGameViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var countdownTimerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pointsLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var initialCountdownLabel: UILabel!

    var seconds = 5 
    var timer = Timer()
    var isTimerRunning = false 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue
        UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")

         }

    func runTimer() {

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self,   selector: (#selector(UIViewController.updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: try self.updateTimer do not add UIViewController

Answer (score 0):

you need to create an updateTimer function first to be used in your selector function of the scheduledTimer function. 
make sure you decorate it as objc.

Also make remove the UIViewController in the selector function since the function is only present in YOUR current viewcontroller class(InGameViewController) and not the parent UIViewController class.

```
    @objc func updateTimer() {
             print("timer updated")
    }

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self,   selector: (#selector(updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

UIViewController does not have a property called `updateTimer`

I do not think you can just call a property in a `#selector()` as it has the wrong signature and will fail.

for reference the API reference to what you are calling:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/1412416-scheduledtimer

Answer (score 0):

```
class InGameViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var countdownTimerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pointsLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var initialCountdownLabel: UILabel!

    var seconds = 5 
    var timer = Timer()
    var isTimerRunning = false 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue
        UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")

         }

    func runTimer() {

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self,   selector: (#selector(self.updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}

@objc func updateTimer() {
             print("timer updated")
    }
```